# thread.name give me two different answers in my code

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I got two ways out of the program.

First:

```
namespace FirstTheard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            T1.Name = "Primery Thread";
            T1.Start();

        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            var threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                { 
                    label1.Text += "ThreadName is-------"+threadName+"\n";
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> Output:
>   ThreadName is-------Primary Thread

Second:

```
namespace FirstTheard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            T1.Name = "Primery Thread";
            T1.Start();

        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            //var threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                { 
                    label1.Text += "ThreadName is-------"+ Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "\n";
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> Output:
>   ThreadName is-------

Why are two outputs different?

please help me

Comment: Because ```Invoke``` will run your piece of code in different thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Thread.CurrentThread.Name` gives you the name of the thread which reads this property.

In the first case, you access (read) this property on your created thread `T1`.
In the second case, you access the property on the UI thread (because of calling via `Invoke`). And since you didn't set any name for the main UI thread, the property returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` returns control back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sample, you are accessing the `Thread.CurrentThread.Name`
 in the Thread `t1` i.e. the `t1.Name`

Whereas, in the second sample, you are accessing the `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` within `Invoke`, which, in this case will be the main GUI/Event thread, which does not have any name. Remember, [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) will execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood
Thank you everybody

This code show my means

```
namespace FirstTheard
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string CurrentThread;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Position of thread now is "Primery Thread"
        CurrentThread = Thread.CurrentThread.Name= "Primery Thread";
        label1.Text = CurrentThread + "\n";
        Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
        T1.Name = "Secondery Thread";
        T1.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        //Position of thread now is "Secondary Thread" or T1
        var threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //Position of thread now is "Primery Thread" again
                label1.Text += "ThreadName at T1 is-------"+ threadName + "         " + "ThreadName in the Invoke is-------" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name+ "\n";
            }));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

}
```

}